# When do we have $(AB)^T= AB$?

Tags: matrices, transpose

When is it true that $(AB)^T= AB$? I'd say that if $A$ commutes with $B$ it is true, but i don't know if there is any other case where this is true.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Have you tried anything? I claim that almost any attempt to construct an example of $A,B$ where $(AB)^T = AB$, where $A$ and $B$ do not commute and neither is symmetric, will work.

Comment: I m trying to find every solution, not just an example

Comment: @GiuseppeFontanella I think the point they're making is that once you found a couple examples it won't be hard to find all of them.

Comment: I know but it would be helpful if you d say to me what is the general matrix that maked true the statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, then $(AB)^T=AB$ iff $B^TA^T=BA=AB$, that is your relation is true iff $A$ and $B$ commute.

However, if $A$ or $B$ is not symmetric, $A$ and $B$ need not commute, here is a counterexample:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}6&1\\1&4\end{bmatrix}$$

Then $(AB)^T=AB$ but $AB\ne BA$.

Comment: Another counterexample is when $A=0$, $B$ can be whatever.

Comment: @lcv But then it's not a counterexample to the statement that $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: Then is it possible to find a (sufficient) condition that always makes the statement true ?